# Fields of type numeric return wrong value

Tags: laravel, firebird

Versions:

- Firebird 3.0 with PDO
- Laravel 7

I'm using the Eloquent and I'm using package for connection with database https://packagist.org/packages/harrygulliford/laravel-firebird.

OBS: In Windows Serve work very well, but in Linux don't (In CentOS 7 and Ubuntu Server 20.04LTS).

I'm using Laravel with Firebird and I've problems with fields of type NUMERIC that return wrong values.

Example:
A query that should turn back 190,65, returns 0.0001.

This is the SQL DDL:

```
Item::selectRaw("CODIGO,DESCRICAO,PRECOVAREJO,PRECOATACADO,PRECOESPECIAL")->get();
```

This is return in json:

```
{ "data": [ { "CODIGO": "123456", "DESCRICAO": "DESCRIPTION EXAMPLE", "PRECOVAREJO": "0.0001", "PRECOATACADO": "0.0001", "PRECOESPECIAL": "0.0001" } ] }
```

Create Table:

```
CREATE TABLE ITENS ( PRECOVAREJO NUMERIC(15,3), PRECOATACADO NUMERIC(15,3), PRECOESPECIAL NUMERIC(15,3), CODIGO VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL, DESCRICAO VARCHAR(80) );
```

[image]

[image: Image example return using Postman]

@Mark Rotteveel
This is the query builded by Eloquent Laravel:

array:2 [ 0 => array:3 [ "query" => "select count(*) as "aggregate" from "ITENS" where "ITENS"."DATACANCELAMENTO" is null" "bindings" => [] "time" => 33.17 ] 1 => array:3 [ "query" => """select CODIGO, DESCRICAO, PRECOVAREJO, PRECOATACADO, PRECOESPECIAL from "ITENS" where "ITENS"."DATACANCELAMENTO" is null order by "CODIGO" asc fetch first 10 rows only """ "bindings" => [] "time" => 8.39 ] ]

This is return expected
[Image return expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yEpb.png)

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Your screenshots don't really help without the actual DDL, sample data and the query or code producing the wrong results.

Comment: Please include sample data, and if possible, the actual query that Laravel generated.

Comment: you can use TraceAPI on Firebird 2.5 or newer to see the real query. IBExpert or free http://FBProfiler.sf.net and perhaps many other GUI tools can use TraceAPI and log the SQL statements for you

Comment: @JosiasFonseca What is the point of notifying me if you haven't updated your question with the details I asked for?

Comment: I updated in question with the query that the builded by Eloquent and return of the database expected

Comment: Given the screenshot shows the right result when the query is executed on Firebird, I would guess that the problem is either in Laravel, or Laravel is connecting to a different database than you're querying manually.

Comment: Why is there when you creating field PRECOVAREJO NUMERIC(15,3) on next image there is size 0 and scale 2/3. There should be size 15.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by updating the PHP version to version 7.4.16.
The problem was resolved in version 7.4.0

I also created a file in /etc/php.d/30-pdo_firebird.ini with the content: extension = pdo_firebird.

https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.4.0
resolve the bug
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65690

Thanks to everyone who helped